# PAMI - PHP Asterisk Manager Interface

Tags: php, asterisk, amazon-ami

I have successfully installed PAMI and I can get get events from AMI to my php script. But My question is how can I send that data to another web page, when specific event called. Php script is always run, due to infinite loop. It always listen to events coming from AMI.

Any one have idea please tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to add some code details. Questions saying "how do I do this" are better suited to Asterisk forums and such.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380437/ami-event-listener

Comment: Were you able to do this? I am in the same boat and having difficulty with understanding and implementing.

Answer (score 0):

Can suggest you go this tag and see answers.

There are no any diff between general events and asterisk events

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-handling